# Why changing SelectedItem in one Combo changes all other Combos?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I populated comboboxes in this way

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
     if (c is ComboBox)
     {
         (c as ComboBox).DataSource = DataSet1.Tables[0];
         (c as ComboBox).DisplayMember = "Articles";
     }
}
```

But, problem is when I change SelectedItem in one Combo - it becomes changed in all other Combos?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bind them each to a separate instance of the DataSet1.Table[0].

ie)

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is ComboBox)
    {
        DataTable dtTemp = DataSet1.Tables[0].Copy();
        (c as ComboBox).DataSource = dtTemp 
        (c as ComboBox).DisplayMember = "Articles";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou GrandMaster. Solved.

Comment: Depending on the number of ComboBoxes and the amouut of data in your DataTable, this could lead to a large increase in the memory footprint of your application due to duplicate of the data.

Comment: @cadrell0 - Good point, I'd not considered that and had assumed it would only be a for a couple of combo boxes.

Comment: The following answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24121888/638977), shows that no need extra memory.
`cmbApprover1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();`

Answer (score 6):

A better approach would be to use a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) to avoid duplicating the data.  Also, don't cast multiple times if it can be avoided.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = c as ComboBox;

    if (comboBox != null)
    {        
        comboBox.DataSource = new DataView(DataSet1.Tables[0]);
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "Articles";
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I just realized you can do  this even cleaner with LINQ

```
foreach (ComboBox comboBox in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
    comboBox.DataSource = new DataView(DataSet1.Tables[0]);
    comboBox.DisplayMember = "Articles";
}
```

Comment: This is a much better way to do this.   The accepted answer would have a much larger memory footprint.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem but I was working with generics. I've used the binding context of the combo box to get rid of this.  (Very useful when you don't know the size of the binding list - in your case it's 5 items)

In the below code DisplayBindItem is just a class with Key and Value.

```
    List<DisplayBindItem> cust = (from x in _db.m01_customers
            where x.m01_customer_type == CustomerType.Member.GetHashCode()
            select new DisplayBindItem
            {
                Key = x.m01_id.ToString(),
                Value = x.m01_customer_name
            }).ToList();

    cmbApprover1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
    cmbApprover1.DataSource = cust;
    cmbApprover1.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cmbApprover1.ValueMember = "Key";

    //This does the trick :)
    cmbApprover2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
    cmbApprover2.DataSource = cust ;
    cmbApprover2.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cmbApprover2.ValueMember = "Key";
```

The Class for you reference.

```
    public class DisplayBindItem
    {
        private string key = string.Empty;

    public string Key
    {
        get { return key; }
        set { key = value; }
    }
    private string value = string.Empty;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

    public DisplayBindItem(string k, string val)
    {
        this.key = k;
        this.value = val;
    }

    public DisplayBindItem()
    { }
}
```

Please mark as answer if this solves your problem.