# Control changing control on other UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a User Control that contains a combobox/drop down list. This user control is used multiple times and added dynamically to a panel. When I change the value of the combobox on one user control, it changes the rest? Does anyone know how to sort this?

[image]

So to clarify. When I change the value in the combobox of the top usercontrol (7002), it will change the second user controls combobox value to whatever I selected.

Thanks!

Code for adding the controls;

```
foreach (Common.UserDTO UDTO in BLL.User.GetAllUsers())
{
    Admin_UserControls.UserBar UB = new Admin_UserControls.UserBar(UDTO);
    UB.Location = new Point(0, int.Equals(pnlUserBlock.Controls.Count, 0) ? 0 : pnlUserBlock.Controls[pnlUserBlock.Controls.Count - 1].Bottom);

    pnlUserBlock.Controls.Add(UB);
}
```

constructor/load events:

```
private Common.UserDTO UDTO;

public UserBar(Common.UserDTO UDTO)
{ 
    InitializeComponent();

    /* Store the passed in UserDTO */
    this.UDTO = UDTO;
}

private void UserBar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* Setup the Drop down list */
    cbRanks.DataSource = Common.Helper.GetRanksDT();
    cbRanks.DisplayMember = "Rank";
    cbRanks.ValueMember = "ID";

    /* Setup the users */
    lblUsername.Text = UDTO.Username;
    cbRanks.SelectedValue = UDTO.RankID;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: Are you reusing the same instance of the UserControl when it is added dynamically?

Comment: Added some code. @haddow64 I'm not using the same instance no, create a new one each time.

Comment: Is likely the `cbRanks.DataSource = Common.Helper.GetRanksDT();` if you bind each instance of the UserControl to a seperate DataSource that should fix it see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261468/why-changing-selecteditem-in-one-combo-changes-all-other-combos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261468/why-changing-selecteditem-in-one-combo-changes-all-other-combos)

Comment: @haddow64 Yeah that's sorted it, cheers mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the above comment into an answer should others have the same issue in future.

Each instance of the `UserControl` that is created is bound to the same `DataSet` giving you this result.

Caused by the line:

```
cbRanks.DataSource = Common.Helper.GetRanksDT();
```

To resolve this simply declare a new instance each time the `UserControl` is created, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261468/why-changing-selecteditem-in-one-combo-changes-all-other-combos) that discusses a few methods.